# Efficient way to check all points around a given point

Tags: javascript, optimization, canvas, points

Hey, I recently wrote this fairly simple [game of life](http://jsfiddle.net/yfS8q/) in JavaScript.

Within this script I check all cells around a given cell, I currently do this via *eight* if statements.

It works but just feels wrong and hard coded. Would there happen to be a faster, more efficient way of doing this? Or are masses of if statements the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating an array of offsets and looping through the array?

```
var offsets = [{dx:1,dy:1},{dx:0,dy:1}, ...
```

Comment: I like the idea, I will just throw together a quick [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) and see what happens :)

Comment: Well the if statements are still faster, not sure why. Heres [the test](http://jsperf.com/checking-all-points-around-a-point). Hmm, this is a tough choice, I think I just need to speed up the loops rather than the if statements.

Comment: Probably less computation involved with the if statements... guess it's a tradeoff.

Comment: Yeah, I will accept this because it would be faster with more checks, just not in my case. I have realised the potential for optimisation lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize that, for example instead of checking if x > 0 many times, put just one wrapping the other ifs

```
if(x > 0) {
    if(cells[x - 1][y]) 
        alive++;

    if(y > 0 && cells[x - 1][y - 1])
        alive++;

    if(y < edgeAmount && cells[x - 1][y + 1]) 
        alive++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a lookup table that gets updated after some steps, so you speedup calculations